# Is the p-adic Lindemann-Weierstrass Conjecture still open?

Tags: transcendental-number-theory, p-adic

**The *p*-adic Lindemann-Weierstrass Conjecture**: Let $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{N}\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{p}}$
  be distinct $p$-adic algebraic numbers satisfying $\left|\alpha_{n}\right|_{p}<p^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}$
  (so that $\exp_{p}\left(\alpha_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{C}_{p}$) for all $n$. Then, $\exp_{p}\left(\alpha_{1}\right),\ldots,\exp_{p}\left(\alpha_{N}\right)$
  are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I'm a graduate student who is considering taking on this problem for my doctoral dissertation

[This article from 2008 by M. Waldschmidt](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/AWSLecture5.pdf) says that the conjecture is still open (it lists it as conjecture 5.16).

I was wondering if that was still the case.

Comment: The question does not ask for advise, but I wonder whether it is advisable to choose for a Ph.D. project a problem that for a decade has resisted solution by experts.

Comment: I suippose that $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_N$ are meant to be distinct. Or maybe linearly independent over the rationals.

Comment: Yes, they are distinct. I've fixed that. :)

@CarloBeenakker: Call me crazy (I probably am), but I think I might have made a breakthrough on the problem. I've gone through my proof line-by-line several times over already, and nothing is out of place. 

To give a hint of what I'm doing, the argument hinges on two propositions:

Comment: (continued)

1) (Already known): certain zeroes of power series over a complete non-archimedean field are algebraic over said field.

2) (I had to prove it): a non-trivial linear combination of algebraic translates of the Iwasawa logarithm is never analytic at the point at infinity of the complex p-adic numbers.

Comment: @mcs-> Did you publish your proof?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a 2018 paper, [A Note on One-dimensional Varieties Over the Complex p-adic Field](https://www.ejpam.com/index.php/ejpam/article/view/3281), that still lists the "full" statement as a conjecture; "half" of the statement, meaning that at least $\lfloor N/2\rfloor$ of the exponents are independent, has been proven by [Nesterenko.](http://math.tsukuba.ac.jp/ant/Sympo/dioph06_abst/Nesterenko.pdf)

Comment: What is the citation information for that one-page flyer by Nesterenko that you linked? I'd like to use it. :)

Comment: the full article is: Yu.V. Nesterenko, Algebraic independence of  $p$-adic numbers, Izv. Math. 72, 565-579 (2008); https://doi.org/10.1070/IM2008v072n03ABEH002411 ; "half of the Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem" is corollary 2 in that paper